# Bootstrap - class text-center is not working on inner div

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

i am trying to apply text-center class of bootstrap on my google captcha. it is not working. here is my code.

```
<div class="text-center"><div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="<?php echo get_option('recaptcha_site_key'); ?>"></div></div>
```

is it not working because of google captcha or there is some other problem. for all other ,  or something it works.

most of the answers are like that i have to add this code

```
style="width: 78%; margin: 0 auto; display: block;"
```

actually this worked but it is not responsive solution. please provide a responsive solution.

Comment: what version of bootstrap? and show more code I mean if you wrap this `div` in `row` or something?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tryied class ***mx-auto*** ?
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/

Comment: is it a bootstrap class ??

Comment: no it did not work.

Comment: Here's some small workaround:

    <div class="row justify-content-md-center"><div class="col-md-auto g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="<?php echo get_option('recaptcha_site_key'); ?>">xx</div></div>

Comment: no it did not work.

Comment: It seems your other styles may overwrite bootstrap's css